# How do I Take certain elements of a String array and create a new array java

Tags: java, arrays, string, file

so I am currently writing a program that reads in inputs from a file. (I am a beginner in java and don't understand a lot yet, so if you guys can work with me being slow that would be great.)

The file consists of a whole bunch of information regarding country data based on sales of products. The two pieces of the file that I care about are the Country names and the profit numbers. What I'm stuck with is how do I take specific portions of the file and read them into an array and then tally up the total profits? Currently I have read in the header of the file, found the indexes of the Country and profit of the header ( I assumed that finding the index of the headers will translate to finding numbers and names for profit and country later on). The file for example has multiple countries and they repeat multiple times through the file in a random order. Ex

[image]
Any help will be useful thanks!
my code right now is:

```
 public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException{

    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("sample-csv-file-for-testing-fixed.csv"));
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("Output.csv"));

    // gets first line of file
    String firstline = in.nextLine();
    firstline.trim();
    String data = firstline.replaceAll(" ","");
    String[] header = data.split(",") ;

   
    // find index of Country and Profit and store them into variables
    String country = "Country";
    String profit = "Profit";

    int index1 =0 , index2=0;
    for(int i = 0;i<header.length;i++){
        if(header[i].equals(country)){
            index1 = i;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<header.length;i++){
        if(header[i].equals(profit)){
            index2 = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(index1+" "+index2);


    while( in.hasNextLine()){
        String line = in.nextLine();
        String nextline = line.replaceAll(" ","");
        String[] values = nextline.split(",");
        for(int i = 0;i< values.length;i++){
            System.out.print(values[i]+ " ");
        }
   }
    

    // Read in line of file into string, separate the string into an array
    // keep track of country names
    // find a way to get rid of all other numbers except profit
    // sum the total profit for each line for each country
    // create a output file and print out the table 

}
```

Comment: To clarify, are the data records not uniformly formatted? I.e., is it correct that the profit appears at index 4 on some records and at index 5 on others?

Comment: So the profit will show up on the same index everytime. so if profit for one row is in 11, it will be in 11 for every other row. The countries them selves are not in alphabetical order so profits for each country will be jumbled through out the file

Comment: Hm, maybe your data should be corrected, seeing as you have profit at index 4 on some and index 5 on others.

Comment: No its in index 4 for everything. Sorry that comment was a bit confusing

Comment: OK, as long as it's consistent it should work. Does my sample below help at all?

Answer (score 0):

If I don't understand bad, you want something like this:

```
public static final String COUNTRY_HEADER = "country";
public static final String PROFIT_HEADER = "profit";

public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    final Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("src/main/resources/group-by.txt"));
    final String firstLine = in.nextLine();
    final String[] headers = firstLine.split(" ");

    int countryIndex = -1;
    int profitIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        if (headers[i].equalsIgnoreCase(COUNTRY_HEADER)) {
            countryIndex = i;
        } else if (headers[i].equalsIgnoreCase(PROFIT_HEADER))  {
            profitIndex = i;
        }
    }

    final Map<String, Long> profitsByCountry = new HashMap<>();
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        final String line = in.nextLine();
        final String[] values = line.split(" ");

        profitsByCountry.merge(values[countryIndex], Long.valueOf(values[profitIndex]), Long::sum);
        }

    profitsByCountry.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.printf("Country: %s, Profit: %d%n", key, value));

    // Do more stuff
}
```

Basically, once you have located the index of the columns you are looking for, you just need to go throw the rest of the lines in the file and accumulate their values.

*Note: The data example you have offered has one mistake, there is an extra 'blah' in the last line for 'USA'*

Comment: When trying to run this i get an index out of bounds exception error. Also is there a way to do  this without using a hashmap?

Comment: Also what does the -> do?

Comment: The `->` is for lambda. I have not added any controls for null values or not index found to avoid to do the code messier but, if you make sure the file exists (notice my example has a different file name/location) and remove the extra 'blah' in USA, it should work

Comment: i changed the file to the name of the file i have, The blahs are only for the example my real file is much different than that. Even still the program doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

A File Stream based solution. Finding the index of the header uses the same logic as @Dave and @fjvierm.

```
public class FileStreaming {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("filestreamdata.txt"))) {
            int[] idx = getIndex(br.readLine());

            Map<String, Integer> result = br.lines()
                                            .map(l -> l.split(" +"))
                                            .map(ss -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(ss[idx[0]], Integer.parseInt(ss[idx[1]])))
                                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                                                    AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue,
                                                    Integer::sum));

            result.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.printf("%s %d\n", key, value));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static int[] getIndex(String line) {
        String[] splits = line.split(" +");
        int[] result = new int[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
            if (splits[i].equals("country")) {
                result[0] = i;
            }
            if (splits[i].equals("profit")) {
                result[1] = i;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is way out of the realm of my understanding... so i have no idea what is going on here

Answer (score 0):

The below code might help.

It assumes: the header is always the first line; the header record begins with "Segment"; and the profit values are always in the same field position as the “Profit” header.

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.stream.*; 

public class SumTheProfit {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  
    String fileName = "test.csv";
    String firstColumnHeader = "Segment";
    String profitColumnHeader = "Profit";
  
    // put header record into an array
    Path filePath = Paths.get(fileName);
    String[] firstLine = Files.lines(filePath)
      .map(s -> s.replaceAll(" ", ""))
      .map(s -> s.split(","))
      .findFirst()
      .get();
    
    // get the index of "Profit" from the header 
    int profitIndex = java.util.Arrays.asList(firstLine).indexOf(profitColumnHeader);
        
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // filter out header record & collect each profit (index 5) into a list
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
      list = stream
        .filter(line -> !line.startsWith(firstColumnHeader))
        .map(line -> line.split("\\s*(,|\\s)\\s*")[profitIndex])
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    //sum each profit value in the list
    Integer sum = list.stream().mapToInt(num -> Integer.parseInt(num)).sum();
        
    System.out.println(sum);
  }
}
```

This takes a declarative approach using the Java Streams API, as that's easier to read in comparison to an imperative *for loop* approach that hides application logic inside boilerplate code.

Comment: This is what i get when i run it : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 29

Comment: What data are you using? Can you update your data sample to reflect the data you're using - or a better approximation?

Comment: OK, that changes the code, since your header row now starts with "Segment"

Comment: I updated the code. Try it now and see what happens. For me, it worked with a .csv (comma-separated) file. But it didn't work if I first opened that file in Excel. I think because Excel messes with the csv formatting somehow.

Comment: I still am getting the same error. I don't know what is happening honestly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224498/discussion-between-dave-and-j-woodchuck).

Comment: I updated the code. Should now be able to handle any number of spaces or commas between values.